# Как восстановить подключение в убунту 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Люди добрые, помогите пожалуйста:
Комп на убунту не видел беспроводные сети(сетевая карта имеется). Я решил, что проблема в дровах и скачал подходящие. Но во время установки выдало ошибку и теперь даже по проводу не могу подключиться к сети, пишет "не удалось активировать сетевое подключение". Как восстановить?

Comment: Ну Вы, для начала, хотя бы показали, какие сетевые интерфейсы видит Ваша система: "ip link show".

Comment: А как ты ставил дрова?